# Property or method "Name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm having a problem in closing my modal inside the template in vue.js

Here's my code:

```
var something = new Vue({
    el: "#something",
    data: {
        showModal: false
    }
});

Vue.component("mymodal",
{
    template: `
      <button class="button" @click="showModal=false">Cancel</button>
    `
});

export default something;
```

Here's my html

```
<div id="something">
        <mymodal v-show="showModal"></mymodal>
        <button @click="showModal = true" class="button is-info">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

Basically, my modal for opening is working properly. Just the close modal that's trigger inside the template in my .js file that I have an error that says,

> Property or method "showModal" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
>   either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

Comment: The error is quite descriptive here: your component doesn't have any property named `showModal`. Can you show how this component is used in your root html?

Comment: Hello @raina77ow. I added codes and tags in my html

Comment: It is looking for a method instead of changing the **showModal** variable because that variable is in other component, not in the modal component

Comment: I suggest to use event emitters to complete your modal functionality

Comment: I already tried to use methods: for events in opening and closing, but I still have the same issues.

Comment: Yes, but your showModal is declared in parent component, you can't access it from your child component, not in the way you tried to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var something = new Vue({
    el: "#something",
    data: {
        showModal: false
    }
});

Vue.component("mymodal",
{
    template: `
      <button class="button" @click="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
    `,
    methods : {
        closeModal() {
            this.$emit('closeModal');
        }
    }
});

export default something;
```

And in your html:

```
<div id="something">
        <mymodal v-show="showModal" v-on:close-modal="showModal = false"></mymodal>
        <button @click="showModal = true" class="button is-info">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh I'm having a warning that says, "Event "closemodal" is emitted in component <mymodal> but the handler is registered for "closeModal". Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "close-modal" instead of "closeModal".

Comment: Try with v-on:close-modal="showModal = false". I forgot that rule

Comment: Oh, I tried to use - in my html, the warning is gone but the modal ain't closing.

Comment: That's strange, it should work. What is the value of your showModal after the event is emitted?

Comment: I don't see any values.

Comment: What was the mistake? Please share your final solution, so other people can reach the solution too

Comment: without using emit :)

Comment: I'm just wondering why this doesn't work. @click="something.showModal = false" :/ @JordyGarcia

Comment: So, you solved it accessing directly to the parent data? like "this.$parent.showModal"?

Comment: Yeah. kind a like. Yes accessing the parent showModal